# How to search Spree::Orders and associations with ransack gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, spree, ransack

Using Spree and ransack, how is it possible to return the Spree::Variants included in Spree::Orders that have completed since a certain date? The ransack documentation gives a little advice about searching associations, but does not seem to go deep enough.

```
Spree::Order
  has_many :line_items

Spree::LineItem
  belongs_to :line_item
  belongs_to :variant 

Spree::Variant
  has_many: line_items
```

Orders that have completed can be searched with:

```
  o=Spree::Order.complete.ransack(completed_at_gt: '2015-05-01')
```

But how to find the Spree::LineItems within these orders and return the Spree::Variants' SKUs within these orders is unclear.

I'm attempting to use ransack because this will be used in a Spree report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use ransack in this area at all. ActiveRecord will let you do what you need:

```
Spree::Order.complete.where(
  Spree::Order.arel_table[:completed_at].gteq(
    Date.new(2015, 10, 1)
  )
).joins(
  line_items: :variant
).select(:sku).distinct.pluck(:sku)
```

If you must use ransack, you can get the ActiveRecord relation, using `.result` and apply the joins and such.

```
Spree::Order.complete.ransack(
  completed_at_gt: '2015-05-01'
).result.joins(
  line_items: :variant
).select(:sku).distinct.pluck(:sku)
```

Since you don't have `.pluck`, you're running a really old version of Spree that is pre-Rails 4. You can get the results by using:

```
Spree::Order.complete.ransack(
  completed_at_gt: '2015-05-01'
).result.joins(
  line_items: :variant
).select(:sku).map(&:sku).uniq
```

Comment: The question specifies that ransack is required because it seems that ransack is de facto for spree reports. I've updated the question to reflect this.   Besides:-   `undefined method 'pluck' for #<Arel::Nodes::Distinct:0x8fcdc00>`

Comment: I've added additional answers based on your feedback. The initial query works on Spree 2.1+, but `.pluck` does not exist in Rails 3, so you'll need to get the values in the alternate way listed.